# add div with error in case of wrong validation for username and password angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

how can i add div to html code which appear only if the username and password wrong (there is no user or password match this data ) by using angular 4 and typescript

login.component.html :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSignin(f)" #f="ngForm" class="sign">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-screen">
            <div class="app-title">
                <h1> Login  </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="text" class="login-field"  placeholder="username" ngModel name="UserName" required>
                    <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>

                    <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name">
                        <span style="color: red"> * </span>
                    </label>          
                </div>


                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="password" class=" login-field" placeholder="password" ngModel name="Password" required>
                    <span><i class="fa fa-lock" ></i></span>
                    <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass">
                        <span style="color: red"> * </span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" [disabled]="!f.valid" (click)="onSignin(f)" >الدخول &nbsp;
                    <i class="fa fa-sign-in" ></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

login.component.ts:

```
 onSignin(form: NgForm){
  const UserName = form.value.UserName;
  const Password = form.value.Password;

  this.authService.signinUser(UserName,Password);
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
signinUser(UserName,Password){
return this.http.get('http://api.###.com/api/###/signin?
  username='+UserName+'&password='+Password)
 .map(res => res.json())
 .subscribe(
   data => {
     if (data.Id == 0){
     console.log('error');
     console.log('something error');

    }
    else{
      this.router.navigate(['/calendar']);
      console.log('Ok');
   }}
 )
}
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `control.setErrors({invalid: true});` on return inside the subscription.

You might need to move the subscription part from service to component:-

So in service:

```
signinUser(UserName,Password): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://api.###.com/api/###/signin?
        username='+UserName+'&password='+Password);
}
```

And in component:

```
`onSignin(form: NgForm){
    const UserName = form.value.UserName;
    const Password = form.value.Password;

    this.authService.signinUser(UserName,Password).subscribe(response => 
        {
            // Login Success
            ...
        }, 
        errorResponse => {
            // Login Error
            form.controls['UserName'].setErrors({invalid: true});
        }
    );
}`
```

On the html:

```
<div [hidden]="!UserName.errors.invalid">
     There is no user or password matching this data.
</div
```

Please refer this [tutorial](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-2-forms-tutorial-validation-efcd6756025b)

Comment: Thank you for helping, but i have error in form.UserName.setErrors({invalid: true}); .. as property 'UserName' doesn't exist on type 'NgForm' .

Comment: Try form.controls['UserName']

Comment: The same error :  TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined .

Comment: Ok looks like you are unable to get the control. To make it simple for you do this.:- Instead of doing this `form.controls['UserName'].setErrors({invalid: true});` simply do `invalid=true;` you will have to define the variable in your component `let invalid: false;`  and in html simply use `[hidden]=!invalid`.

Comment: sorry i want some declaration , i should define invalid = true in my ts component ? or let invalid : false?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Define `let invalid = false;` in you component.ts. It should be initially false so that you don't get the error div shown initially for the first time page loads.

Comment: the previous error was it can't read errors , could u update ur explanation in ur updated comment please? i'm confused